# Attempting to optimize a pixel reading and outputing function

Tags: php, css, html, pixel

```
$img = imagecreatefrompng("img/".$image); 
    $w = imagesx($img); 
    $h = imagesy($img); 
    $pixelcount = 0;

    echo "<div id='container' style='width: {$w}px; height: {$h}px;'>\r\n";
    for($y=0;$y<$h;$y++)    { 
        for($x=0;$x<$w;$x++)    { 
            $rgb = imagecolorat($img, $x, $y); 
            $r = ($rgb >> 16) & 0xFF; 
            $g = ($rgb >> 8) & 0xFF; 
            $b = $rgb & 0xFF;
            $alpha = (imagecolorat($img,$x,$y) & 0x7F000000) >> 24;
            if($alpha == 127)
                $newcolor = "transparent";
            else
                $newcolor = sprintf('#%02X%02X%02X', $r, $g, $b);
            if(isset($prevcolor) && strcmp($newcolor, $prevcolor) != 0)
            {
                echo "<div style='background: {$prevcolor}; height: 1px; width: {$pixelcount}px; float: left;'></div>\r\n";
                $pixelcount = 0;
            }
            $prevcolor = $newcolor;
            $pixelcount++;
        }
        echo "<div style='background: {$prevcolor}; height: 1px; width: {$pixelcount}px; float: left;'></div>\r\n";
        unset($prevcolor);
        $pixelcount = 0;
    } 
    echo "</div>\r\n";
```

Here's a link to the tool in its current form.

http://schnell.dreamhosters.com/folio/pixelread.php?image=link.png

Mousewheel up, I and +/= key zoom in. Mousewheel down, O and -/_ key zoom out.  No need to focus on any particular element, the entire document registers a keystroke/mousewheel.

Edit - Thanks for the fix that that one problem, guys!  Got a new one now though.  If you go to the tool and attempt to blow it up by zooming in, the sprite just falls apart.  If you leave it alone and do nothing, it looks fine.  What's weird too is that you can't fix the picture by reseting the size, it will stay messed up until you refresh the page.

Edit2 - Found the source of the trouble.

```
function resize(width, height)
    {
        $('div#container').css('height', factor * height);
        $('div#container').css('width', factor * width);
        $('div#container > div').css('height', factor).css('width', function(i, val) { return parseInt(val * factor) + 'px'; });
        $('div#container').css('margin-top', ($(window).height() - $('div#container').height())/2 + "px");
    }
```

Width isn't getting multiplied by 'factor' for some reason.  I'm trying to do it in such a way that jQuery does it to each and every child div, basing the new width off the old, without having to do a huge for loop or anything, but nothing I'm coming up with is working.

Edit3 - Finally got it working!  I just stored the original lengths of each div as the 'id' attribute in each and then access that when it comes time to resize everything.  Thanks to everyone who put up with this and stuck with me to see it through.  I swear the resizing is smoother than before!  :D

Comment: This may be a stupid question, but why do you want to do this?

Comment: Honestly, I don't even know myself.  lol.  It's just for my own fun and sort've a learning experience.  I know it's pretty impractical.  Also I think it's neat that I've made a tool that can basically blow up NES sprites to gigantic proportions without the limitations of the Chrome/FF browser zooms.

Comment: Is this a PHP or an HTML issue?  Is it that the function doesn't produce the HTML you want, or that the HTML is not being rendered the way you want in the browser?

Comment: I believe it's a PHP issue.  The HTML seems to all be correct, but the calculations behind the scenes aren't coming out right.  For instance, in one sprite I have, you have 10 pixels of transparency, 3 pixels of #050505, then the rest of the line is transparency.  However, the output comes out to be a 10px long div of transparency, then a 13 pixel div of #050505, then some other ridiculous amount that shouldn't be.  So, yes, the PHP isn't producing the HTML it should be.

Comment: +1 for blowing up NES sprites  :-)

Comment: While originally reading your description my head did a 90-degree "what the..." twist to the side, but after reading the comment about it being just for fun and seeing it in action, I have to admit it's actually pretty nifty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code isn't resetting the pixel count after each run of colour.  I think you need this:

```
    if(isset($prevcolor) && strcmp($hex, $prevcolor) != 0) {
        echo "<div style='background: {$prevcolor}; height: 1px; width: {$pixelcount}px; float: left;'></div>\r\n";
        $pixelcount = 0;
    }
```

Comment: Yeah I just found that on my own too.  lol.  Thanks.  But now I've got a new problem, see above.

Comment: Looks likes the width of colour-run divs isn't being increased along with the height.

Comment: I see function(i, val) { return parseInt(val * factor) + 'px' } in your page source.  Should it be function(i, val) { return parseInt(val) * factor + 'px' }  ?

Comment: Yep, just did that and it sorta works.  But now zooming in too much makes it really blow out of proportion.  Shrinking is also borked, gotta fix that.

Comment: Ok, I figured it out.  I need a way to store the base length of each div so I can access it later and multiply it by 'factor'.  If I keep trying to apply 'factor' to the previous widths, it'll exponentially get out of hand.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that the problem lies in the fact that, in the inner loop, you never reset `$pixelcount` after you use it. Consequently, it's just an accumulation of the total pixels of the row, meaning that each time you print you get a progressively larger width.

Based on your description, you'd want to reset it when you switch colours:

```
if(isset($prevcolor) && strcmp($hex, $prevcolor) != 0) {
    echo "<div style='background: {$prevcolor}; height: 1px; width: {$pixelcount}px; float: left;'></div>\r\n";
    $pixelcount = 0; // Incremented back to 1 below
}
```

The resizing problem comes from the resize function, where width is now set inappropriately because the base width of each block is no longer 1:

```
var cssObj = {
    'width' : factor, // This factor needs to be multiplied by the original width
    'height' : factor
};
$('div#container > div').css(cssObj);
```

I'm sure there's a better way to do this, but you could get the width upfront:

```
$('div#container').css('margin-top',
    ($(window).height() - $('div#container').height())/2 + "px");
$('div#container > div').each(function() {
    $(this).data('originalWidth', $(this).width());
});
```

...then in the resize function:

```
$('div#container > div')
     .css('height', factor)
     .css('width', function() {
         return $(this).data('originalWidth') * factor;
     });
```